# Unqualified-id in file included from ZXBinarizer.mm

Tags: objective-c, xcode, zxing, objective-c++

I have created an iPhone project that uses uses the ZXing bar code scanning library.  I added ZXing using CocoaPods and it works perfectly when I compile it on my system (Mountain Lion with Xcode 4.5 (4G182)).  But when I passed it on to the person in charge of producing the signed ipa for enterprise distribution, who from what I understand is also using the same version of Xcode, he is seeing the following parse error when compiling:

```
Parse Issue
Expected unqualified-id in file included from /The/Absolute/Path/to/Pods/ZXing/objc/src/ZXing/ZXBinarizer.mm
```

The line that is highlighted is:

```
#import <ZXing/ZXBinarizer.h>
        ^
```

I was able to look at his system via WebEx and I checked the header search paths and the values that were apparently configured via CocoaPods do resolve to the actual location of the files.

When I clicked on the  "Parse Issue" line in the issue navigator, it showed only:

```
../../ZXing/objc/src/ZXing/ZXBinarizer.h
^
```

I've searched the web quite a bit for a solution and I see plenty references to 'Expected unqualified-id', but most of them are due to malformed code.

There are still quite a few things about Xcode that I do not understand, so I'm hoping that someone will tell me that I've overlooked something simple here.

Comment: I've confirmed that this project compiles with no issues on two other systems, both with the latest Xcode and both running Mountain Lion. Unfortunately, the problem appears to be only on machine of the fellow who's responsibility it is to sign it for distribution.  I will be attempting to do another remote debugging session next week.  Any suggestions would be be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any chance the project build settings got tweaked on the failing machines? Can you get the build/compile lines for the file in error from a good and bad machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to revert out of using CocoaPods for dependency management and just include the project manually.  Since the problem was on someone else's machine, but worked fine on my own, I was unable to determine the real cause.  After I just included ZXing directly in my project, he was able to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Posting links to the exact code being compiled would help.

You can use `clang -E` to see what the code looks like after preprocessing (with all the #imports expanded), and then `diff` the preprocessed output on your system against the output of the same command on your colleague's system.

I do see in
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/objc/src/ZXing/ZXBinarizer.h
that they're referring to `NSObject` without #importing `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` first. This is a bad idea, but it's probably not your actual problem. (I would expect a different error message if it were the culprit.)

Are you 100% sure that your colleague is compiling ZXBinarizer.mm as Objective-C++, not as regular C++?

Are you 100% sure that Xcode doesn't give you any specific file and line information for the error? If Xcode really is just pointing to an `#import` line, then can you post the 10 lines before and after that line, and also the first 10 lines of the file being #imported?

Comment: He was unzipping workspace on his system and attempting to compile it without making any changes. I can only assume that it was something to do with his system as it related to CocoaPods at this point.

Answer (score 0):

**smcmahon**, I've had a very similar issue with building an iOS project with CocoaPods and seeing those weird errors, and was able to figure out the problem. Make sure that the symlinks that CocoaPods has created (like `ZXing/ZXBinarizer.h`) are indeed symlinks, and not just regular text files with a filepath in them.

A bit more detailed explanation is in my blog: http://www.egeek.me/2013/01/26/note-about-building-cocoapods-powered-ios-projects/

Hope this will help.